# CSS menu bar style sheet menu does not render

Tags: javascript, css

I have a project that needs a CSS menu bar with panel of overview panels on the right side of HTML page. My issue is the that the CSS menu bar style sheet menu does not render. Attempting to get this CSS menu bar working, then extend code functionality for content links, login, dashboard, etc.

Code:  tag

```
<header class='header'>
    <div class='header_top-bar'>
        <div class='top-bar_title'>
            <a href='index'><h1><img src='images/logo.png' data-image='images/logo.png' alt='Athena'></h1></a>
            <div class='ajax-loader' id='ajax-loader'>
                <div class='ajax-loader_animator'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='top-bar_toggle' id='menu_toggle'>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class='top-bar_share' id='share_toggle'>
            <span class='underline--white'>
                SHARE
            </span>
        </div> -->
        <div class='top-bar_menu' id='overlay_menu'>
            <ul class='menu_container'>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.01.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/'>Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.02.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/project'>Athena Customers</a>
                </li>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.03.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/wines'>Athena Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.04.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/sustainability'>Athena Sustainability</a>
                </li>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.05.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/hospitality'>Athena Dashboards</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class='language-chooser menu_item'>
                <div class='masi-agricola_wrapper hide-on-mobile'>
                    <a href='http://www.masi.it' target='_blank' class='masi-agricola_link'>
                        <img src='images/agricola.png' data-image='images/agricola.png'/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <p class='text--subtitle'>select your language</p>
                <span class='language-link'><a class='' href='/en/'>Eng</a></span>
                <span class='line-break'></span>
                <span class='language-link'><a class='' href='/es/'>Esp</a></span>
                <span class='line-break'></span>
                <span class='language-link'><a class='' href='/it/'>Ita</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Code: content section

```
<div id="new-plh" class="plh"></div>
<div id="actual-plh" class="plh">  
    <section class="main-content clearfix homepage">
        <div class="main-content_background">
            <div class="half_screen full-height-desk" id="biggest_block">
                <a href="project" class="">
                    <div class="text-block">
                        <div class="full-image_header page-header">
                            <h1 class="page-header_title text--title">
                                Athena Intelligence Earth's Essential Data
                            </h1>
                            <strong class="page-header_subtitle text--subtitle">
                                Athena Intelligence Login
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                        <img data-image="images/project-header.jpg" src="images/project-header.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="half_screen full-height-desk">
                <a href="wines">
                    <div class="text-block three_row">
                            <div class="full-image_header page-header">
                                <h1 class="page-header_title text--title">
                                    Athena: Many industries: all use Land, Food, Energy, Water
                                </h1>
                                <strong class="page-header_subtitle text--subtitle">
                                    The Gods: Land, Food, Energy, Water
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <img class="three_images" data-image="images/wines-header.jpg" src="images/wines-header.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="sustainability" class="">
                    <div class="text-block three_row">
                            <div class="full-image_header page-header">
                                <h1 class="page-header_title text--title">
                                    Land, Food, Energy, Water: Sustainability
                                </h1>
                                <strong class="page-header_subtitle text--subtitle">
                                    Athena : Dedication To Land, Food, Energy, Water
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <img class="three_images" data-image="images/sustainability-header.jpg" src="images/sustainability-header.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="hospitality">
                    <div class="text-block three_row">
                            <div class="full-image_header page-header">
                                <h1 class="page-header_title text--title">
                                    Land, Food, Energy, Water: Hospitality
                                </h1>
                                <strong class="page-header_subtitle text--subtitle">
                                    Land, Food, Energy, Water: That Welcomes You
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <img class="three_images" data-image="images/hospitality-header.jpg" src="images/hospitality-header.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Code: title bar wrapper tag

```
    <div class='out-loader_wrapper'>
        <div class='out-loader'>
            <div class='filler' id='filler'>
                <img class='logo-loader' src='images/logo.png' data-image='images/logo.png'/>
            <div class='filler-bar'></div>
            <p class='text--title' id='loader_text'>0</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the CSS file for anyone who wished to view it, just ask

Comment: Is the issue that none of your CSS takes effect?  (this would imply that you're linking it into the html file incorrectly, so please show us how you're doing that.)  Or is some of the CSS working, but not all of it? (In which case you need to describe what's not working as you expect it to, and, yes, of course you need to include the relevant code in the question.)

Comment: The CSS is large - <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'>

Comment: The JS scripts <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js')</script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

Answer (score 0):

Given you did not post the complete HTML I cannot tell if you are linking the stylesheet correctly. Nothing in your HTML looks out of place, which means that if you can't see the styles rendered then either the stylesheet was not linked correctly to the document or you did not import it correctly if you're using a preprocessor like SASS or LESS.

However, you can try the following:

1. Make sure you're linking it correctly in your document's `<head>` like `<link href="path/to/your/menu-stylesheet.css rel="stylesheet">`.
2. If you're linking multiple stylesheets, make sure to link them in the correct order. This means that if you reference classes or styles that are declared in another stylesheet, you must ensure to link the stylesheet that is referenced before the stylesheet that makes the reference.
3. If you're using a preprocessor, make sure you imported the stylesheet correctly like `@import 'path/to/stylesheet.less` (mind the correct extension whichever your case.
4. If you're using a task runner like grunt or gulp, you can concatenate your stylesheets into one single stylesheet.

Comment: thanks - I do have the CSS linked - <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'>